# Single SKAction Animation on several nodes using a loop with completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, completionhandler

Objective: Apply a single SKAction Animation on several nodes using a loop, while waiting for completion handler.

```
    func animateShuffle(cards: [Card], completionHandler:(success: Bool) -> Void) {
    var rotationInRadians:CGFloat = CGFloat(M_PI)
    var rotateFirstDeck = SKAction.rotateByAngle(rotationInRadians, duration: 1.0)
    var moveFirstDeck = SKAction.moveToX(-150, duration: 1.0)
    var returnToOrigPosition = SKAction.moveToX(-125, duration: 1.0)
    var firstDeckSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveFirstDeck, rotateFirstDeck, returnToOrigPosition])
    var rotateSecondDeck = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-rotationInRadians, duration: 1.0)
    var moveSecondDeck = SKAction.moveToX(-100, duration: 1.0)
    var secondDeckSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveSecondDeck, rotateSecondDeck, returnToOrigPosition])


    for (index, Card) in enumerate(cards){

        if index % 2 == 0{
            Card.image.runAction(firstDeckSequence)
        }
        else{
            Card.image.runAction(secondDeckSequence)
        }
    }

    //hack
    cards[0].image.runAction(firstDeckSequence, completion: { () -> Void in
        completionHandler(success: true)
    })

}
```

Here I call the function which kicks off another Animation:

```
animateShuffle(newDeck.deck, completionHandler: { (success) -> Void in
        print("entered")
        var drawnCards = [Card]()
        if let areThereCards = newDeck.drawCards(4){
            drawnCards = areThereCards
        }
        self.dealCards(drawnCards)
    })
```

I used a hack to get to 99% of where I want to be but my gut tells me there is better way to do this. How can I tell when the last node has finished animating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sequences run for 3 seconds so when the first completion block runs you can safely assume they are all done. To be 100% certain set a bool ivar in the completion handler and then run your post-sequence code in the `didEvaluateActions` method of the scene.

Alternatively count how many sequences you run, then increase a counter in completion block, and run your code when both counters match.